# Where is / are your luggage?

Tags: verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

If I have two luggages, which of the following sentences is right?

> 1. Where is your luggage?
> 2. Where are your luggage?

Comment: *Where is your luggage?* is okay. If you are not happy with it, you can ask *Where are your total pieces of luggage?*

Comment: If I want to asked a person whether he has found the two pieces of luggage, should I ask "Have you find it? "or "Have you find them?"

Comment: "Luggage" does not have a plural, so "Where is your luggage?" is correct.  The individual items that make up your luggage would be referred to as "pieces of luggage", so you might ask, "Where are all your pieces of luggage?"--I wouldn't recommend "total pieces".  "Learning":  "Have you found them?" (not "find them") is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation (having two articles of luggage), 1. "Where is your luggage?" makes more sense.

Luggage does not have a plural form and can be addressed as one single thing.
If you expressed luggage as, for example, a suitcase, then 2. would be correct. This is because of the plural of 'suitcase', suitcases agree with 'are'.

EX. A) "Where are your suitcases?"
    B) "Where are your suitcase?"

'A' makes more sense.

Comment: Why is your B sentence taking *are* with the singular 'suitcase'? Why can't it be *Where is your suitcase?*